# Pulling data from my rest api into my VueJS component's array data property

Tags: node.js, rest, express, vue.js

I've been studying `Vue.js` for weeks and developing a Rest API backend using `NodeJS express` which i want to connect to it.  I already have the Rest API working and serving up JSON for me.  Now I'm trying to get that `json` and store it in an array in one of my Vue components using `vue-resource`

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "error": null,
    "response": [
        {
            "TxnID": "277731-1507125498",
            "SalesRep": null,
            "QuoteNumber": "20822PF",
            "QuoteModified": "2017-10-23T17:46:25.000Z",
            "Customer": "Dquard",
            "Country": "Indonesia",
            "QuoteAmount": 9106,
            "SalesOrderNumber": "19289",
            "SalesOrderAmount": 9106,
            "IsFullyInvoiced": "true",
            "status": "WIN 100%",
            "type": null,
            "margin": null
        },
        {
            //more data
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to put each `response` in an object of arrays.  I'm trying to do this in a method:

```
methods: {
    loadData () {
      this.$http.get(this.url)
        .then(response => {
          return response.json()
        }).then(data => {
          const resultArray = []
          for (let key in data.response) {
            resultArray.push(data[key])

          }
          console.log(resultArray)
          // this.salesOrders = resultArray
        })
    }
```

But when the console displays `resultArray` it's just a bunch of `undefined`:

[image]

Do I need to change the way my Rest API serves up the json?  Ideally, I'd like each response object in my json to serve up each record as a key/value pair.  For example `SalesRep: 'Jason'` instead of string/string like `'SalesRep':'Jason'`

Comment: Think you meant to do this `resultArray.push(data.response[key])`.

Comment: haha, that was indeed it.  And it automatically formatted my json as key/value.  Thank you!

Comment: If you'll add this as an answer I'll accept.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your `for` loop, you are not accessing the response array.

```
for (let key in data.response) {
    resultArray.push(data.response[key])
}
```